# Excel - How to make auto-adjusting range formula for a cell?

Tags: excel, automation

I was wondering if it is possible to make a formula that auto-adjusts its scope based on how the sheet grows. Here's an example to illustrate:
[image]

Currently, cell B16 is calculating the sum from B2 to B15. Suppose that in the future, I keep filling up the rows with items and costs and reach cell B15 (Everything is now filled up. **If I want to add more items, I will insert a new row at B16 and the 'Total' Row becomes B17.**

But the formula will not self adjust, and the range will remain at B2:B15. **Is there a way to go about automating the process to self-adjust the formula range when I insert new rows?**

I'm new to Excel, but I do have programming experience if that matters. Other alternative methods to go about solving this are also welcome. Thank you!

Comment: When I test it Excel expands the range if it is inside the formula.  So if you highlight row 16, right-click and select "Insert" the formula will change to `=SUM($B2:$B16)` Does it not do that for you?  If it doesn't you can use the OFFSET function to manipulate the range.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yeah somehow it doesn't do that for me! Can you elaborate on how I can use OFFSET? Searched around but I'm still unsure.

Comment: I'd convert the data to a table and add a Totals row - can add 1m rows of numbers then and your total will still be at the bottom calculating correctly.  No complicated volatile formula then - just a tick box to tick in your table design tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the sum you want to calculate, then it's fairly easy, because an empty cell is considered having value 0.

So, you can put your formula in another column and replace it by `=SUM(B$2:B$1048576)`.

Remark:
The value 1048576 is based on my maximum number of rows. You can check that value pressing <kbd>Ctrl + ↓</kbd>.

If you really want to have the sum in the same column, you might use this formula:

```
=SUM(B$2:OFFSET(Bxxx,-1,0))
```

Where `Bxxx` is the cell reference where you are putting this formula.

Comment: I get that this is possible, but is there a way to do this such that the formula is in the same column?

Comment: @Yui: I edited my answer according to your comment.

Comment: Thank you! I also arrived at the same answer, though I didn't know OFFSET can be used directly inside the sum formula so I ended up defining a cell called "LastCell" that uses OFFSET and using that in SUM.